# Eclipse doesn't see ".a" libraries

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, linker, libraries

I'm working on Windows and I use MinGW, and I builded all libraries. I added them to all settings.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

I'm fighting this problem for a couple of days, and that is all I've got.

[image: 4]

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you built the three static libraries in question yourself.

Conventionally the GCC toolchain expects static libraries to have names
of the form `lib<name>.a`.

In order for a static library to be found by the linker as satisfying the
option `-lfoo`, it must be called `libfoo.a`, not `foo.a`. If the library
is, unusually, called `foo.a` then for the linker to find it you need to
pass it the unusual option `-l:foo.a`.

So you can either:-

Rename your libraries:

```
glew32.a -> libglew32.a
glfw3dll.a  -> libglfw3dll.a
SOIL.a ->   libSOIL.a
```

Or change your Eclipse library (-l) settings:

```
glew32 -> :glew32.a
glfw3dll    -> :glfw3dll.a
SOIL -> :SOIL.a
```

I suggest the first alternative, as there is no reason why you shouldn't
follow the usual naming convention for libraries you are building yourself.

Comment: Yes, just figured that out. But anyway, thank you so much, I didn't know that theres a naming convention for libraries.